# declaration of static function outside of class is not definition

Tags: c++, static

I am getting this error when I compile with GCC:

```
error: declaration of 'static int utils::StringUtils::SplitString(const std::string&, const std::string&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&, bool)' outside of class is not definition
```

**Code:**

**Header:**

```
namespace utils
{
    /*
    *   This class provides static String utilities based on STL library.
    */
    class StringUtils
    {
    public:
        /**
        *   Splits the string based on the given delimiter.
        *   Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1114/STL-Split-String
        */
        static int SplitString( const std::string&              input, 
                                const std::string&              delimiter,
                                std::vector<std::string>&       results, 
                                bool includeEmpties =           true );
    };
};
```

**Source:**

```
namespace utils
{
    int StringUtils::SplitString(   const std::string&          input, 
                                    const std::string&          delimiter,
                                    std::vector<std::string>&   results, 
                                    bool                        includeEmpties );
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to lose that semicolon in your source file.  Should be:

```
namespace utils
{
    int StringUtils::SplitString(   const std::string&          input, 
                                    const std::string&          delimiter,
                                    std::vector<std::string>&   results, 
                                    bool                        includeEmpties ) // <--- No more semi-colon!
    {
    ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the header file? The one you copied doesn't have a semicolon on the end.

Comment: @CodeGuru, Right - I was pasting what the source file *should* be

Comment: @Code-Guru: yeah, Eric showed the corrected definition from the source file by omitting the semi-colon which was there in the original post.

Comment: @paddy I don't see a semicolon in that part of the code in the OP...and it hasn't been edited. However, I see one at the end of the snippet that declares the class (which is presumably a header file).

Comment: @Code-Guru, that's odd because it really is there!  Perhaps the DIV element is being clipped poorly, or you need to scroll horizontally.

Comment: The OP has two code snippets. One ends in a semi-colon, the other does not. (At least on my end.) Your original answer showed the latter one.

Comment: @Code-Guru, I think I see the confusion - the semi-colon that was removed was not after a curly brace - it was after a closing parenthesis in the second code snippet.

Comment: @Code-Guru, good edit. Probably would have saved us about 10 minutes :)

Comment: That 10 minutes was very entertaining! At least *I'm* getting a chuckle out of my noob behavior...

Answer (score 11):

Take the semi-colon off the end of the definition in your source file!  Copy-paste error =)

Comment: could you explain why the semicolon caused the error, what is the meaning of the error?

Comment: Because the syntax for function _definitions_ do not have a semi-colon before the body of the function. This is a super common mistake that's usually from copy/pasting the declaration from a header, then defining the function body and forgetting to remove the semi-colon from the copy/pasted declaration.